# Flutter ios Handle background notification in terminated status app

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, silent-notification

i have an issue when handling silent push in my app when the user close the app, here is my native code which works like charm when the app in the foreground, background or terminated status from a short time from closing the app, and after long time from closing it (+30min) it will not work anymore, it make me confuse why it does not work and other messaging app like viber, whatsapp and messanger you can still receive messages and calls even you swipe the app and close it !! is there any thing must i add !!

```
override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
            Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
            if Auth.auth().canHandleNotification(userInfo) {
                completionHandler(.noData)
                return
            }
        
        // sample notification for testing
            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            content.title = "Hi there"
            content.body = "Just test"
            content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default
            
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "helloNotification", content: content, trigger: nil)
            
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { (error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error adding notification request: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
            }
        // resent to dart side
        let controller: FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
        let notificationChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "notificationHandler", binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
        var dataToSend: [String: Any] = [:]

        if let text = userInfo["text"] as? String {
            dataToSend["text"] = text
        }
        
        // Convert the dictionary to NSDictionary
        let nsDataToSend = NSDictionary(dictionary: dataToSend)


        // Pass the NSDictionary to Dart
```

i double checked :

background capabilities : remote notifs, background fetching, voip, background processing

I tried using background handler of firebase_messaging and handle it natively using swift and same problem, the app stop handling silent push after closing it after a short time

and this is the postman payload :

```
{
    "data": {
        "title": "You have new message",
        "body": "New message(s) recieved."
    },
    "content_available": true,
    "notification" : {

    },
    "apns": {
        "payload": {
            "aps": {
                "contentAvailable": true,
                "sound" : "default",
                "mutableContent": true
            }
        },
        "headers": {
            "apns-push-type": "background",
            "apns-priority": "5"
        }
    },
    "to": ""
}
```

Comment: Voip apps can make use of voip push which will relaunch the app if it is terminated. Non voip apps cannot use this and will therefore not receive background notifications if they are terminated.

Comment: thanks for replay, i updated my question and added the payload snippet to check it

Comment: That is a background push. A voip push has `apns-push-type` of `voip` - see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns. But you can only use this push type to report an incoming call. If your app does not report an incoming call in response to a voip push it will be terminated.

Comment: i gave it a quick try and it does not work, honestly i didnt know the idea of voip push at all i will read about it to solve this issue

Comment: Sorry.  I am not being clear. Your app cannot receive push notifications when it is terminated. I was trying to explain why those other apps you listed have different behaviour. Also they are likely to be grandfathered in to old behaviour with a special entitlement from apple that allows them to use PushKit pushes to relaunch without signalling an incoming call.

Comment: after a some googling i fount that must send voip push notification from node js using certificate file and it works, now i have to handle them to show necessary ui

Comment: Yes. You will need to use callkit to report an incoming call

Comment: i run into many issues, at first is fcm support voip push notifs ? i put an print statement into didreceiveIncomingPushWith and seems not triggered yet, i used node-apn and the docs is not clear how to send voip notifs so now im looking for a solution to send voip notification

Comment: Does your app qualify to use voip pushes?  Ie are you going to report an incoming phone call when you receive the voip push? There are specific requirements in the document I linked to; you have to set the apns-topic correctly as well as specifying the push type and ensuring the certificate you have provided to FCM includes the voip capability.  You also have to implement the specific [code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pushkit/responding-to-voip-notifications-from-pushkit) to receive and respond to the voip push.

Comment: sorry for replying too late, yes i want to notify the user is there an incomming call and just i want to extract some data from the notification then resend it back to flutter which i have a plugin that handle every thing and bythway the plugin itself has direct interect with the didReceiveIncomingPushWith, but now im confused how i can send a voip push ? is it supported by fcm or should i switch to onesignal ?

Answer (score -1):

The main reason why you sometimes don't get notifications when the app is termiated may be because you are testing it in the emulator. First test the notifications on a real device.

Comment: absolutely i test it in real device bcz push notification does not work on simulators, and as i mentioned it does not work only after short time from terminating the app